# Receive data as NSArray serialize the object and use each value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swifty-json

I'm am trying to use the data of this request. I don't know how to receive data that comes in NSArray. So what I want to know is how can I use each one of the values that are in the array like "addresses" and "awards"?

(I'm using Swifty framework)

This is the server response and the data what I want to use. or better store it in a variable.

```
 [
        {
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "idAddress": 1,
                    "idProgram": 1,
                    "descriptionAddress": "Address1",
                    "registerDateAddress": "2017-09-12T11:03:53.083",
                    "isActive": true
                }
            ], 

"awards": [
            {
                "idAward": 1,
                "idProgram": 1,
                "nameAward": "Awards1",
                "descriptionAward": "ImagenAward1",
                "imageAward": "ImagenAward1.png",
                "registerDateAward": "2017-09-12T11:03:57.67",
                "isActive": true
            }
        ]
```

**And this is my code:**

```
   func getTheProgram(onSuccess: @escaping(JSON) -> Void, onFailure: @escaping(Error) -> Void) {

    print("xxxxxxxxxx", userId ?? "")
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.my_url.com") else {return}
    var  request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("xxxxxxxxx", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if let response = response {
            print("Response",response)
        }
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! NSArray

                print(json )
                let result = JSON(data: data)
                onSuccess(result)
                print("xxxxxx")


            } catch {
                print(error)
                print("xxxxxxx")
            }
        }

        if(error != nil){
            onFailure(error!)
            print("xxxxxx")
        } else{

        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: This is Swift. Do not use `NSArray`, use a Swift array.

Comment: Don't use `NSArray` in Swift. Cast the result to `as [[String:Any]]` ie an array of dictionaries of type String:Any. Then you can access dictionary from the array and access the sub-dictionaries under the`addresses` and `awards` keys.  Also, nothing in your code is using SwiftyJSON

Comment: Read the JSON. It's pretty easy. `{}` represents a `Dictionary` (subscripted by key) `[]` an `Array` (subscripted by index)

Comment: Ok I'll try with your advices, If something works, I'll let you know.